# Error with sharing message and image through implicit intent

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to be able to share the message and the image in one intent. This works right now partially. For example, when I share it in Google keep, I am able to get the header, text body and the image through intent. However, when I try to send it through email or some other messaging app, I am unable to send the message, only the text and header get attached. I'll get an error saying: unable to attach file.

```
public void characterShare(String background, String header){
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String name = bundle.getString("name");
    Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName()
            + "/drawable/" + name.toLowerCase());

    Intent togetherIntent = new Intent();

    togetherIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    togetherIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,header); // subject
    togetherIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,imageUri); // image
    togetherIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, background); // body of the message
    togetherIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
    togetherIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(togetherIntent, "send"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to be able to share the message and the image in one intent

`ACTION_SEND` is documented to support *either* `EXTRA_STREAM` *or* `EXTRA_TEXT` in a single `Intent`, not both. Some apps responding to `ACTION_SEND` will honor both, but not all.

> However, when I try to send it through email or some other messaging app, I am unable to send the message, only the text and header get attached. I'll get an error saying: unable to attach file.

You are using an `android.resource` `Uri`. That has two problems:

1. It is very obscure, and not all apps will support it
2. It goes against the documentation for `ACTION_SEND` and `EXTRA_STREAM`, which state that the `Uri` should have a `content` scheme and be backed by a `ContentProvider`

The simplest solution is for you to copy your resource to some file on the filesystem (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`), then make it available using `FileProvider.getUriForFile()`. [This sample Java project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/-/tree/v2.0/PdfProvider) and [its Kotlin counterpart](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/-/tree/v2.0) show the basic concept, though I am using an asset instead of drawable resource, and I am using `ACTION_VIEW` instead of `ACTION_SEND`.